# autocite + mcite functionality in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

When using Biblatex's `autocite` command, I sometimes come across instances when I need to format the citations as a reference set. There is the option of using `mcite`, but then I lose the high level markup that autocite offers, .e.g. switching between `plain`, `inline` and `superscript`. If I use `autocite` or `autocites`, each reference would get it's own citation in the bibliography. Is there a solution that offers something like what I call `\mautocite` in this example?

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,mcite,subentry,autocite=plain]{biblatex}
...
\begin{document}
Some text here\autocite{key1}. More text here\mautocite{set1,*key2,*key3,*key4}. 

Cite a subentry\autocite{key3}.

\end{document
```

In the text, it would appear as

> Some text here [1]. More text here [2].
>
> Cite a subentry [2b].

And this would give two entries in the bibliography, where the second reference, [2], would be a set. Is there a way to get biblatex to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mcite-like commands are defined in the biblatex module `blx-mcite.def`. There you will find a citation command modifier `\mcitelike`, used as follows.

```
\newrobustcmd*{<new mcite command>}{\mcitelike<existing citation command>}
```

An mcite-like `\autocite` is somewhat odd because `\autocite` is intended to be  style-independent, but mcite-like commands are relevant only to numeric citation styles. That said you can define an mcite-variant of `\autocite` with:

```
\newrobustcmd*{\mautocite}{\mcitelike\autocite}
```

Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,mcite,subentry,autocite=superscript]{biblatex}

% just for demo
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{firstinits,sorting=none}

% define mcite-like variant of \autocite
\newrobustcmd*{\mautocite}{\mcitelike\autocite}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\mtextcite{companion,bertram,knuth,*knuth:ct:a,*knuth:ct:b} showed that...
Filler text \autocite{knuth:ct:a}.
Filler text \mautocite{model,*weinberg,*glashow}. 
Filler text \autocite{weinberg}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that here `\mtextcite{companion,bertram,knuth,*knuth:ct:a,*knuth:ct:b}` is the equivalent of:

```
\defbibentryset{knuth}{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\textcite{companion,bertram,knuth}
```

Similarly `\mautocite{model,*weinberg,*glashow}` becomes:

```
\defbibentryset{model}{weinberg,glashow}
\autocite{model}
```

Futher details can be found in the biblatex manual sections "mcite-like Citation Commands" and "Dynamic Entry Sets". Various label number and entry set bugs were introduced/fixed between versions 1.1 and 2.7, so you should upgrade to the latest biblatex and biber releases to get all relevant features working properly.

Comment: Cheers! This is the solution I was looking for!

Comment: @SamuelTan My initial post uncovered a bug, which I documented [here](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/147). The fix will be in the next release, but it is pretty easy to apply yourself.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind biblatex provides the set entry:

```
@SET{a-set,
     entryset={key2,key3,key4},
    }
```

In your example this would then follow like this:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,mcite,subentry,autocite=plain}
...
\begin{document}
Some text here\autocite{key1}. More text here\autocite{a-set}. 

Cite a subentry\autocite{key3}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: mcite-like commands are for defining dynamic (on-the-fly) entry sets. Sets defined with `@set` are static. This is still relevant information, though, so +1.